# Kerberos Delegation and Authentication: Impact due to Domain change

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos, domain-name, kerberos-delegation

[I'm fairly new to Kerberos Protocol]

We have a customer, who back in 2020 was using a domain let's call it `customdom.itm`, which has a user account **krb-test-cd** setup for Kerberos delegation and this domain is part of a domain Active Directory forest `itm`.
Since they're a large corporation with many users across different countries, they also have another huge domain AD forest with many child domains (and domain controllers) as part of this forest let's call it `top.abc`. Here the domain relevant to us is `aust.top.abc`, which has **krb-test-aust** user account setup for Kerberos.

Since the forests `itm` and `top.abc` are different, the same servicePrincipalName for both **krb** users is safely set to `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com`, while their userPrincipalName is of course different, i.e.:

1. **krb-test-cd** uPN is `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com@CUSTOMDOM.ITM`
2. **krb-test-aust** uPN is `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com@AUST.TOP.ABC`

And since `https://testloadbalancer.com` is part of the **intranet sites** at the customer, their browsers do not challenge the users to enter their AD credentials.

**Now here's the problem**:
Last month the customer decided to migrate the users in `customdom.itm` to a new domain `can.top.abc` which is part of forest `top.abc`. The user **krb-test-cd** and some other accounts were not migrated, however, and `customdom.itm` still exists in its own forest.
Due to the migration, these users are now challenged everytime to enter their AD credentials and are granted access only with the old domain name, i.e.
`customdom\michael` and `password`

I have setup a new user account **krb-test-can** in the domain `can.top.abc` for Kerberos delegation with **setspn** and the SPN `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com`, and the first time, I got this error:

```
The operation failed because SPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide.
```

Next, I tried **ktpass** with SPN `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com@CAN.TOP.ABC`, and I get another error:

```
Failed to set property 'servicePrincipalName' to 'host/<host name>' on
Dn 'CN=<CN Name>,CN=Users,DC=<DC Name>,DC=<DC Name>,DC=abc': 0x13.
WARNING: Unable to set SPN mapping data.
```

Later, I finally understood that the SPN is already set to user **krb-test-aust**.

**My question is**:
How can I still successfully assign the SPN `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com` and eventually UPN `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com@CAN.TOP.ABC` to the user **krb-test-can** without affecting Kerberos delegation to user **krb-test-aust**?
Or is there a workaround on how I can use **only** the user **krb-test-aust** to delegate Kerberos authentications to the users now residing in domain `can.top.abc` without the need for user **krb-test-can** at all?

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

[Some background]
We have an Access Management software on our side where we have configured many Identity Providers, 2 Policy Enforcement Points and Kerberos authentication for SingleSignOn for each of the above 2 domains.
We only need to inject the uPN and the password of the **krb** users into the respective PEPs and the software doesn't require a keytab file.
We are identity providers and the customer uses some links like `https://testloadbalancer.com/xyz/efg_idp/entityid` to make an IdP initiated login and is redirected to the target application.

Comment: You can't. SPNs are unique per-*forest* so trying to add an existing SPN to krb-test-can is impossible as long as krb-test-aust has it registered. Your options are to pick a new SPN (and by extension the DNS name of the LB), or make it work with *just* the krb-test-aust principal.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the clarification. How can I make it work with just krb-test-aust users' principal? Is there a Workaround? (like how I asked in the 2nd question)

Comment: Well in theory you should be able to just set the load balancer SP to the krb-test-aust account and credentials and it should work.

Comment: @Steve You mean that there's a cross-domain trust which should be able to handle this? If yes, how can I setup this?

Comment: You can create a forest trust between `customdom.itm` and `can.top.abc` and add what's called a top-level-name to the trust for `testloadbalancer.com`. OR you can configure `testloadbalancer.com` to use the account in `aust.top.abc`. There's already a trust between CAN and AUST since they're in the same forest.

Comment: @Steve I think I will go with the 2nd approach of configuring the ```aust.top.abc``` account. But if you'd like, please also shed some light on how to create the forest trust and how to add the "top-level-name" as an answer rather than a comment and I will accept it as an answer here! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a hint from Steve, I finally found the solution to my own problem:
Since the domains `can.top.abc` and `aust.top.abc` and other domains are part of the same forest `top.abc`, they SHOULD have a cross-domain trust (I'm not sure if the trust is default or needs to be setup separately).

Hence, I only need the user account **krb-test-aust** to delegate Kerberos authentications to the users residing in all domains under `top.abc`.
The uPN of **krb-test-aust** remains `HTTP/testloadbalancer.com@AUST.TOP.ABC`.